# Less bounty values

Tags: discussion

I saw that the bounty values are starting form 50rep. What if we can have values lesser than 50. It is not required to award a question with minimum 50rep. If there can be some more values to award as a bounty starting form 25 then it can be possible to  drag more attention to a question asked by an user who has less reputations.

Comment: You mean you want to start bounty when you have less than 50 rep?

Comment: No I want the bounty offers to be less than 50rep.

Comment: Yes. I know that I need minimum 75rep to start a bounty. I appreciate that but I am not getting why the minimum amount is 50? Why can't I award someone with 10reps?

Comment: Instead of awarding 10 rep. you can upvote that answer!

Comment: Why would you want to give anyone anything less then 50 when an upvote is +10 and an accepted answer is +15. Do both and they already get +25. If they give a good answer they can gain 50 reputation points in one day without even trying hard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is just right. To be considered a fully-fledged member of the site, gaining 50 rep is easy in a single day.

The bounty system is to get attention for questions that are difficult to answer, not an express support queue. A question can only receive a bounty after 2 days anyway, more than ample time to get 50 reputation.

I honestly think 90% of users that set bounties are misusing the system due to lack of understanding. You're paying for **advertising** your question, **not express support**.

Also, it's easy to get 25 reputation on a single answer. Just accept it and up-vote it, and you have given someone 25 reputation points. With that in mind, what would my motivation be to answer a question when I don't get any more for my effort then I can normally?

Comment: I visited few user profiles and found out that they are not even gaining single rep a day but they are have more than 200reps. So they are eligible for bounty but they can't spare 50 reps out of 200rep for a single question.

Comment: @user1865284 That sentence makes no sense. Do you understand what the bounty system is really for? Not everyone uses bounties. I never have and I have more then 2k rep on most sites I am active on? Some users get 100 rep because of the association bonus from being a high rep user on another site. I really suggest you read the FAQ around SE and the FAQ tags on meta, and understand how the software works.

Answer (score 1):

Lowering the minimum rep offered for bounty would only serve to water-down the featured question queue. If the question is genuinely in need of more attention (or is worthy of more attention) then it's worth 50 points (at least!). A 25 point minimum would simply encourage gaming the rep system (i.e. always promoting your own mediocre questions in hope of drawing a few votes) and would make it harder to find genuinely deserving posts.

Just earn a few more votes and offer a worthwhile bounty if the question deserves it.